# Join two tables with AWK, one from stdin, other from file

Tags: awk, gawk, csv

I have two tab-delimited files:

file tmp1.tsv:

```
1    aaa
2    bbb
3    ccc
4    ddd
5    eee
```

file tmp2.tsv:

```
3
2
4
```

I want to get this:

```
3    ccc
2    bbb
4    ddd
```

Using following routine:

```
$ cat tmp2.tsv | awk -F '\t' <magic here> tmp1.tsv
```

I know how to make it without stdin:

```
$ awk -F '\t' 'FNR==NR{ a[$1] = $2; next }{ print $1 FS a[$1] }' tmp1.tsv tmp2.tsv
```

But have no idea how to make it with stdin. Also, explanation of the solution will be appreciated.

Comment: Check this: http://theunixshell.blogspot.in/2012/12/file-comparisons-using-awk-match-columns.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your solution works as desired, it is trivial.  Instead of:

```
 awk -F '\t' 'FNR==NR{ a[$1] = $2; next }{ print $1 FS a[$1] }' tmp1.tsv tmp2.tsv
```

simply do:

```
 < tmp2.tsv awk -F '\t' 'FNR==NR{ a[$1] = $2; next }{ print $1 FS a[$1] }' tmp1.tsv -
```

(Note that I've replaced `cat tmp2.tsv |` with a redirect to avoid UUOC.)

That is, specify a filename of `-` and awk will read from stdin.